# MySQL InnoDB specific partition remove and restore

Tags: mysql, innodb

Is it possible to drop a specific partition in InnoDB and later restore it again?
The reason behind this is to archive old partition and restore it again incase it needs to be access.

I been searching around and so far do not see anything promising.

Answer (score 2):

If your are using mysql 5.6:

```
create table dest like source; alter table dest remove partitioning;
alter table source exchange partition XXX with table dest;
```

- you can dump & load data later;
- or you can use innobackupex to backup `dest` table and restore it later using [transportable tablespaces](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-copying.html)

Comment: Thanks ravnur, yes I am using 5.6. Do you know exchange partition will reinsert all rows or it is simply a tablespace move? I did not make it clear on my question that the partition involved is multi terabytes in size, if exchange partition is doing a dump and load, it will take forever.

Comment: selected tablespace will be moved out of table, almost instantly. But be aware of moving it back: operation will require some time. I think, you should test it